# How can I select and option with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is my first select box:

```
echo "<select class='selectpicker abc' name='abc'>";
echo "<option ";
    if ($abc == "a" ) {
        echo 'selected '; 
    }
echo "value='a'>a</option>";
echo "<option ";
    if ($abc == "b" ) {
        echo 'selected '; 
    }
echo "value='b'>b</option>";
echo "<option ";
    if ($abc == "c" ) {
        echo 'selected '; 
    }
echo "value='c'>c</option>";                
echo "</select>";
```

And this is my second select box:

```
    echo "<select class='selectpicker' name='select'>";
    echo "<option class='op1'";
        if ($select == 1 ) {
            echo 'selected '; 
        }
    echo "value='1'>1</option>";
    echo "<option class='op5'";
        if ($select == 5 ) {
            echo 'selected '; 
        }
    echo "value='5'>5</option>";
    echo "</select>";
```

What I wish to do is:

If I choose `a`from `.abc`, then display the options `.op1` and `.op5`. and select the value `1`. If I choose `b` or `c` from `.abc` then display ONLY `.op5` and select the value `5`.

Here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

$(".abc").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'a'){ 
        $(".1").show();
    } 
    if($(this).val() == 'b'){ 
        $(".op1").hide();
        $(".op1").removeAttr('selected'); 
        $(".op5").setAttribute('selected','selected');
    } 
    if($(this).val() == 'c'){ 
        $(".op1").hide();
        $(".op1").removeAttr('selected'); 
        $(".op5").setAttribute('selected','selected');
    }   
});
```

But it is not working. If I select `b` or `c` from `.abc` then always `1` is selected. Not `5`.

Comment: class name should start with a character.

Comment: @Hemal. Thank you. I changed it, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use

```
$('.selector-1').prop('selected', true);
$('.selector-2').prop('selected', false);
```

Also you use bootstrap-select plugin, so you may need to force it's update:

```
$('.selector-1').selectpicker('refresh');
```

**Upd:**

Also try something like this

```
$('.abs').on('change', function(){
 var strValue = $(this).val();
 var objSelect = $('select[name="select"]');

 objSelect.find('option:selected').prop('selected', false);

 if( strValue === 'a' )
  objSelect.find('option[value="1"]').prop('selected', true);
 else if( strValue === 'b' || strValue === 'c' )
  objSelect.find('option[value="5"]').prop('selected', true);

 objSelect.selectpicker('refresh').selectpicker('render');

});
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed everything you said in my code, but my problem is still there

Comment: Can you try something like this in your change event: `$("selectpicker option:selected").prop("selected", false); $(".selectpicker option[value='5']").prop('selected', true);` and after this `$("selecpicker").selecpicker('render');`

Comment: I tried everything you suggested, but then nothing is working anymore. Then I can see always "1" and "5"

Comment: Can you please view this code - https://jsfiddle.net/0kecaxzc/ - this is how i think it work (And it work). Is this solution doesn't work in your code? (And all is identical)

Comment: Thank you, but the fiddle is not showing the result I wish. `a` should have the options `1` and `2`, but `b` and `c` should only have the option `5`. In your example I still can choose `1` when `b` or `c` os selected

Comment: Thank you, but the `1`should not be disabled, it has to be not visible

Comment: You can store object with pair "key from first select" => [ array from last select ]. Then replace your target selec html and update / refresh selectpicker.